# equations involving trig functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Is there a way to solve them by hand?

E.g: $2x^2 + 18y^2 - 4 + \sin(x^2+9y^2) = 0$

I can think of a way to express  $x^2 + 9y^2$ as $t^2$ but i can't proceed.

Comment: what is the solve variable?

Comment: this equation can not be solved explcitely for $x$ or $y$

Comment: set of points (x,y) which satisfy this equation.

Comment: do you mean the implicit function theorem?

Comment: Even if we write $y$ in terms of $x$ using implicit function theorem, wouldn't we still have to deal with the $sin$ function inside the equation?

Answer (score 2):

If we let $x^2+9y^2=t$, we have

$$2t-4+\sin(t)=0$$

One can prove this has only one solution for $t$ around $1.5$, but we cannot solve for it algebraically.  Instead, using Newton's method with $t_0=1.5$, we get

$$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{2t_n-4+\sin(t_n)}{2+\cos(t_n)}$$

$$\begin{align}t_0&=1.5\\t_1&=1.501209721\\t_2&=1.501210073\\t_3&=1.501210073\end{align}$$

Thus, the solution is $t=1.501210073$ out that many decimals.  Then we are left with

$$x^2+9y^2=1.501210073$$

$$y=\frac13\sqrt{1.501210073-x^2}$$

and so the $(x,y)$ solutions are given by

$$(x,y)=\left(a,\frac13\sqrt{1.501210073-a^2}\right)$$

---

Notice that if $t$ were a rational multiple of $\pi$, we'd get a transcendental number on the LHS, but $0$ is algebraic, hence contradiction.  Particularly, $\sin(t)$ is algebraic for any rational multiple of $\pi$ due to the sum of angles formulas.

Thus, $t$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, but sadly if $t$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, the closed form for $\sin(t)$ is unknown, hence, we cannot "algebraically" solve the problem.

Comment: Looks a bit like Kepler's equation...

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Nice trivia catch :D

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Not really.  I only applied Newton's method using three clicks on my calculator.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Haha, but I really do recommend you learn Newton's method.  Pretty nifty.

Comment: Thanks! Finally it seems like i can use my Fortran knowledge to do some iterations for my calculus reports.. or, if 3 steps on calculator yields this accuracy, maybe i can use that for something else.

Comment: @DanyelKoca depends on a few things, like how close we started.  Turns out that $1.5$ was very close to $t$.

Comment: @SimpleArt I just wrote a little code to find the value using Newton's method, and surprisingly, even if you start with 100000 as initial guess, it acquires 6th decimal accuracy in 15th step.

Comment: @DanyelKoca Yes, Newton's method is one of the best numerical methods out there.  If you can take a derivative, you can use Newton's method.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yeah, you are right. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: @DanyelKoca No problem!  Happy holidays!

Comment: @DanyelKoca I've also added a little extra at the end that you may want to check out.